# Chrome App XMLHttpRequest Canceled

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I've got this Chrome packaged app for uploading photos, and on one (and only one) Chromebook it doesn't seem to work.

On line 147 of this file:

```
https://github.com/pkulak/photo-importer/blob/master/js/upload.js
```

a PUT request is sent, which is immediately canceled:

```
http://i.imgur.com/O57hCPe.png
```

I thought maybe it was a permissions thing, but you'll notice that other requests to the same domain succeed. This app works for the same user on a different computer (a Mac), and doesn't work for a different user on the same machine (the Acer C720 Chromebook), so I don't think it's a Google user account issue. There's nothing in the console when the app hangs after the canceled request and neither the success of failure events are triggered on the request. I'm stumped.

Comment: Is the Chromebook on a different channel (dev/beta/stable)?

Comment: No. Everything is on stable, latest version (whatever that is).